# Exception on readerNew.GetEnumerator(), ResX file Could not find a part of the path

Tags: exception

I have an app using windows forms that goes through all the resource files in a new release writes the name value and comment to a csv file. I am ResXResourceReader and the method GetEnumerator to create a IDictionaryEnumerator and go through each resource and add the key and value to a dictionary. Im getting exceptions on some files, for example:

```
{[System.ArgumentException: ResX file Could not find a part of the path 'C:\ibml\SoftTrac CaptureSuite\Utilities\TranslationUtility\TranslationUtility\bin\resources\accept.png'. Line 12017, position 5. cannot be parsed. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\ibml\SoftTrac CaptureSuite\Utilities\TranslationUtility\TranslationUtility\bin\resources\accept.png'. Line 12017, position 5. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\ibml\SoftTrac CaptureSuite\Utilities\TranslationUtility\TranslationUtility\bin\resources\accept.png'.
```

My code for this is below:

```
    private List<object> GetNewResxStrings(List<object> NewlyAddedResxFiles)
    {

        bool breaker = true;
        Dictionary<string, int> Exceptionslist = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var resxfile in NewlyAddedResxFiles)
        {
            breaker = true;
            while (breaker)
            {

                using (FileStream fsNew = File.Open(resxfile.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))

                {

                    ResXResourceReader readerNew = new ResXResourceReader(fsNew);
                    try
                    {
                        IDictionaryEnumerator dictNew = readerNew.GetEnumerator();




                    while (dictNew.MoveNext())
                        {

                            NewFilesAddedToCurrentVersion.Add(dictNew.Key, dictNew.Value);
                        }
                        Dictionary<object, object> temp = new Dictionary<object, object>(NewFilesAddedToCurrentVersion);

                        NewUtilityResxDictionary.Add(fsNew.Name.ToString(), temp);


                        NameOfChangeNew.Clear();
                        NameOfChangeOld.Clear();
                        NewFilesAddedToCurrentVersion.Clear();
                        breaker = false;
                    }
                catch (Exception E)
                {
                        Exceptionslist.Add(E.ToString(), 1);
                        breaker = false;
                        break;

                    }

                }
            }




        }


        return NewlyAddedResxFiles;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had this error after I c/p a path from explorer. Turned out there was a hidden char in the path. Between C and : if I recall. Could that be the problem? Check in excel with MID or LEN.